# UIBarButtonItem-Badge for iOS

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, badge

I am using [this](https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge) control for showing badge on barbuttonitem. It works fine for the first controller or root controller in navigation controller stack. While pushing to another controller, I tried to show badge and I cannot see any effect there.

Comment: This question is rather brief, and I wonder - whilst not being a iOS dev - whether it does not show readers what you have tried. Would you add the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Badge is displayed or not in other viewcontroller

Comment: no badge is not shown in detail view controller

Comment: i am asking about the the badge view. not badge count

Comment: not badge 'view' is not shown in detail view controller

Answer (score 2):

You should first time set badgeValue in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. In this case it'll appear and don't blink, like if you set it in `viewDidAppear`:

```
    - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
        barButton.badgeValue = @"5";
    }
```

Comment: I moved
 `navRightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navRightButton;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.badgeValue = @"1";` to viewDidLayoutSubviews. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `navigationItem` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not recommended because it is not semantic.

The key to your problem is that the badge view is added to `[UIBarButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"]`, but when `UIBarButtonItem` is initialized, `valueForKey:@"view"` doesn't exist yet, so adding a badge fails.

I suggest you try [QMUIBadge](https://github.com/QMUI/QMUI_iOS/tree/master/QMUIKit/QMUIComponents/QMUIBadge), it can solve your problem.

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
rightItem.qmui_badgeInteger = 1;// number
rightItem.qmui_badgeString = @"99+";// or string

// setRightBarButtonItem any time
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem;
```